# How to set default ciphers for Python Requests library when using urllib3 ver > 2.0.0

Tags: python, security, ssl, python-requests, urllib3

urllib3 removed the ability to change DEFAULT_CIPHER in the major version 2.0.0. This was the main way to get around the error:

```py
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSL_NEGATIVE_LENGTH] dh key too small (_ssl.c:600)
```

on the client side.

Is there anyway to change the default cipher now in urllib3 ver > 2.0.0. or another way to get around this error?

Previously I had been receiving the error:

```py
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSL_NEGATIVE_LENGTH] dh key too small (_ssl.c:600)
```

when using the requests library, which I eventually was able to get around using the line:

```py
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
```

However, after getting a new laptop and reinstalling my packages, I began to get the original error again. After doing a bunch of research, I believe the issue is that on my new laptop, I've installed urllib3 2.0.3 which removed the "DEFAULT_CIPHERS" as seen in the [changelog](https://stackoverflow.com) for version 2.0.0: Removed DEFAULT_CIPHERS, HAS_SNI, USE_DEFAULT_SSLCONTEXT_CIPHERS, from the private module urllib3.util.ssl_

Preferably without having to downgrade my urllib3 to an older version, does anyone know how to change the default ciphers again so I can get around the dh key too small error?

Thanks

Comment: The default ciphers are now the system default ciphers. So adapt your system configuration for OpenSSL - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level